# _asyncToGenerator is not defined after transpiling with Babel and Rollup

Tags: javascript, babeljs, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I want to bundle the following code with the Rollup config below. However, when I open it in the browser, I get the following error.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: _asyncToGenerator is not defined`

I followed the instructions in the Babel documentation but it doesn't work.

**App**

```js
const task = () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve());

const main = async () => {
    await task();
};

export default { main };
```

**Rollup Config**

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/split-test-adapter.js',
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'splitTest'
    },
    plugins: [
        babel({
            extensions: ['.js'],
            exclude: ['node_modules/@babel/**', 'node_modules/core-js/**'],
            runtimeHelpers: true,
            presets: [
                ['@babel/preset-env', {
                    'useBuiltIns': 'usage',
                    'corejs': 3,
                    'targets': {
                        'browsers': ['ie >= 11']
                    }
                }]
            ],
            plugins: [
                '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator'
            ]
        }),
        terser()
    ]
};
```

**Package.json**

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "http-server dev/",
        "build": "rollup -c"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.13.13",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
        "rollup": "^2.43.1",
        "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.3.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.10",
        "core-js": "^3.9.1"
    }
}
```